# Function error - File name is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I spin up a script every other week to scrape files for lines with 3 digit record numbers. Doing this so often I thought why don't I just make a function I can import. I wrote this and went to test it. However, when I run the script and execute

`def_recs(filename, out)`

I get 
"NameError: name 'filename' is not defined"
Where "filename" is the name of the file in question I am passing in to scrape.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import re

def get_recs(infile, outfile):
    path = r'<path to my infile file>'
    with open(os.path.join(path, infile),'r') as infile1:
        with open(os.path.join(path, outfile),'w') as outfile1:
            for line in infile1:
                if re.match(r'(.*)\d\d\d(.*)',line):
                    outfile1.writelines(line)
```

It is saved in a file titled "ToolBelt.py" My ultimate goal is to be able to just do a:

```
from ToolBelt import get_recs
get_rec(newfile, out)
```

and have all the records with three digits in a row written to a file called "out" or whatever I pass as the second argument.

Edit: Just to add, when I modify the above code to not be a function:

```
import os
import re

path = r'<path to my infile file>'
with open(os.path.join(path, 'newfile'),'r') as infile1:
    with open(os.path.join(path, 'out'),'w') as outfile1:
        for line in infile1:
            if re.match(r'(.*)\d\d\d(.*)',line):
                outfile1.writelines(line)
```

It runs just fine.

Edit2 : Just tried changing it to

```
import os
import re

def get_recs(infile, outfile):
    if type(infile) != str:
        infile = str(infile)
    if type(outfile) != str:
        outfile = str(outfile)
    path = r'<path to my infile file>'
    with open(os.path.join(path, infile),'r') as infile1:
        with open(os.path.join(path, outfile),'w') as outfile1:
            for line in infile1:
                if re.match(r'(.*)\d\d\d(.*)',line):
                    outfile1.writelines(line)
```

Still getting the NameError. I'm searching online for the proper way to pass string parameters now.

Comment: If you're getting a NameError it suggests you're not quoting the string.

Comment: From your edit: the `NameError` is being raised before the function is being run. Instead of calling `get_recs(filename, outfile)` use `get_recs('filename', 'outfile')`. Pasting the full stacktrace (with redactions if needed) would help.

Comment: You probably need to turn the path into an absolute path. When you import the function from outside the module, `__main__` is the script you import from, which I'm guessing lies in a different path than it.

Comment: @Holloway That did the trick. Do you know why my check for if type(infile)!= string didn't work to convert the file name to a string?

Comment: The function (and therefore that line) was never run. The name error was thrown before it got that far. For the record, you probably why to use `isinstance` instead of using type equality.

Comment: @michael because it errors before getting that far.

Comment: @holloway is it better to use isinstance due to python being object oriented?  I'm still trying to grasp why it was erroring out. Is it that python evaluates the function definition, knows it needs strings and then when it sees a non string argument passed in throws the error before it executes the function?

Comment: If you ignore your function for a bit, and try `print(filename)` in a new file with nothing else, you'll get a `NameError` as well. It's unrelated to your function definition. When you try and call any function, python has to gather the arguments to pass to it first. When you pass in `filename` it tries to look up what that name is a reference to and fails. When you pass in `'filename'` it is a literal string so there is no lookup involved and the string gets passed. You could also have done `filename = 'filename'` and then `print(filename)` and it would have worked.

Comment: @Holloway THANK YOU for your patience and explanation. Just had the "aha" moment this morning after seeing your last comment. I pass a bunch of characters to the function. Python says, well it's not quoted so it's not a string, it's not numbers so it's not a float or int etc. So it must be a variable. Let's see what is assigned to filename. Nothing. Thus. "NameError: name 'filename' is not defined"

Comment: No problem, we all started somewhere. Glad it's starting to make sense - your explanation sounds spot on.